# Generators of a Galois group in SAGEMath

Tags: galois-extensions, sagemath

I have a (potentially silly) question about a problem I've been having with SAGEMath.

Let $K$ be the maximal totally real subfield of the cyclotomic field of conductor $24$, i.e. the number field with defining polynomial $x^4-4x^2+1$. I have defined this as such in SAGE:

`K.<f>=NumberField(x^4-4*x^2+1)`

I then go on to define the Galois group of $K$:

`G=K.galois_group()`

This group has order $4$. If we check the generators of this group by writing `G.gens()`, we get

`[(1,2)(3,4), (1,4)(2,3)]`

If I understand this correctly, this means there are two generators of the group $G$. However, if I write

`G.<g,h>=K.galois_group()`

I receive an error saying that the number of names needs to match the number of generators of $G$. Writing `G.<g>=K.galois_group()` works, but `g` here has order $2$. Why is it that I can't define $G$ in terms of two generators in SAGE?

Comment: Maybe try asking [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/) as well.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis thank you! I was unaware of this forum - I'll try asking there too.

Comment: The [documentation on Galois groups of number fields](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/galois_group.html#module-sage.rings.number_field.galois_group) does not seem to have an example of the usage ```G.<g> = K.galois_group()```, but it does have ```G = K.galois_group(names='y')```, where ```y``` seems to be the generator of the Galois closure of $K$, completely different things.

Comment: You can see this by ```K.<f> = NumberField(x^3-2); G = K.galois_group(names='y'); G[1].as_hom()```. It gives you an endomorphism in the Galois closure of $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sagemath, the syntax `OBJECT.<a,b,c,...> = ...` works if the right side of the equation is properly set up for this; among other things, I believe it looks for an argument called `names` and tries to use `a,b,c,...` for that argument. In the case of `galois_group`, one of the arguments is `names`:

- "names" - a string giving a name for the generator of the Galois
  closure of self, when this field is not Galois.

So in this case, `G.<a,b,c, ...> = K.galois_group()` is not trying to define generators of the group, but instead a single generator for the Galois closure of `K`.

To actually get the group generators, you can instead define `G = K.galois_group()` and then do `g, h = G.gens()`.

Edit: I hadn't read the newest comments before posting this, and I now see that this is repeating some of the same information given by @durianice. I've converted this answer to "Community wiki."